# Iptables not loading new rules after restart Centos

Tags: bash, centos, firewall, iptables

I've created a bash script that adds a rule to the iptables firewall

**Example**

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

**Problem**

After a restart this rule is not applied

What is the best way to save and apply the rules in bash script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save the current rules to a file, use *iptables-save*. For example:

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

To load the saved rules from that file, use *iptables-restore*. For example:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, the above answer didn't work for me.
So instead of restoring the table I added the route entries in

`/etc/rc.local` or 
`/etc/rc.d/rc.local file.`

For example, add

```
sudo ip route add <ipaddr1> via <ipaddr2> dev <device>
```

to

```
 /etc/rc.local
```